# Query: SOQL SOSL Injection in Security Review

Tags: apex, security, checkmarx, soql-injection

While passing the app, I am still getting SOQL Injection errors in checkmarx.
Please advise why this is:

```
L 435: query += fmw.LeadFieldName + ', ';

L 437: query = query.substring(0 , query.length()-2);

L 439: leadRecord = Database.query(query);
```

// code

```
public Class FieldMappingWrapper{
    public String LeadFieldName { get; set; }
    public String AccountFieldName { get; set; }
    public String ContactFieldName { get; set; }
    public String OpportunityFieldName { get; set; }
    //public String customObjectFieldName { get; set; }
    //public String customObjectName { get; set; }
}

// selected field and picklists 
public Class FieldMappingWithSelectOptionWrapper{
    public FieldMappingWrapper selectedAllFeild { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> leadFieldOptions { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> accountFieldOptions { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> contactFieldOptions { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> opportunityFieldOptions { get; set; }
    //public List<SelectOption> customObjectFieldsOptions { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
private void convertLead( Field_Mapping__c fm ){

    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(leadRecord.id);

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

    //Account acc = new Account( Id = lc.getAccountId() );
    //Contact cont = new Contact( Id = lc.getContactId() );
    //Opportunity opp = new Opportunity( Id = lc.getOpportunityId() );

    List<FieldMappingWrapper> fieldMappingWrappers = (List<FieldMappingWrapper>)JSON.deserialize( fm.Field_Mapping_Json__c , List<FieldMappingWrapper>.Class);
    String query = 'SELECT ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId, ConvertedOpportunityId, ';
    for( FieldMappingWrapper fmw : fieldMappingWrappers ){
        query += fmw.LeadFieldName + ', ';
    }
    query = query.substring(0 , query.length()-2);
    query += ' From Lead where Id = \'' + LeadRecord.Id + '\'';
    leadRecord = Database.query(query);
```

Comment: check this [secdev_inject_soql_injection](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/units/secdev_inject_soql_injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the values that you are using to construct the query to prevent an attacker supplying malicious data that would result in unexpected action or returning additional data fields. In your code, it appears you need to escape `fmw.LeadFieldName` using the `String.escapeSingleQuotes()` method.

Comment: Please have a look at updated code

Comment: You don't appear to have updated your code to perform any additional security checks per the two answers you've received.

Answer (score 1):

When building a dynamic query, always make sure the user can access the fields, otherwise they may expose data not meant to be seen:

```
Map<String, SOBjectField> fields = SObjectType.Lead.fields.getMap();
for(Wrapper fmw: userSelectedValues) {
  SObjectField field = fields.get(fmw.LeadFieldName);
  if(field != null && field.getDescribe().isAccessible()) {
    query += field + ',';
  }
}
```